# Weird behavior of SortedList in RecyclerView

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, sortedlist

I'm using SortedList for sorting my data on some parameter let's say "Date"in RecyclerView for making performance better while loading huge data. But I'm observing very weird behavior of it. First of all lemme put some code-

```
mMatchesList = new SortedList<>(Matches.class, new SortedList.Callback<Matches>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Matches o1, Matches o2) {

            int result = 0;

                try {

                    result = DateTimeOperationUtil.dateComparator("dd-MMM-yyyy", o2.MatchDate, o1.MatchDate);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public void onChanged(int position, int count) {

            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, count);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(Matches oldItem, Matches newItem) {

            return oldItem.equals(newItem);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(Matches item1, Matches item2) {

            return item1.hashCode() == item2.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInserted(int position, int count) {

            notifyItemRangeInserted(position, count);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRemoved(int position, int count) {

            notifyItemRangeRemoved(position, count);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {

            notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
        }
    });
```

Here, I have some Matches as which

> I want to sort by date in Descending order

. First time, order is same as I want but

> when I change Date of any Match, then that should be moved according
>   to defined Order. But it's not happening and Data is also not changing
>   of this list.

**EDITED**
I'm updating my list using below code:

```
if (mMatchesList.indexOf(matches) != -1)
        mMatchesList.updateItemAt(mMatchesList.indexOf(matches), matches);
```

> My Matches model class has equals() and hashcode() implemented.

Tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the SortedList class, but did you call updateItemAt(int index, T item)?

Comment: @Achez9 yes I'm calling updateItemAt(int index, int item) method..

Comment: Could you post how you are updating your object, and how you are dispatching that update to the SortedList?

Answer (score 0):

You have not implemented `areItemsTheSame` method properly. you should check if both the items are same i.e either you check by id(primary key if database model) or some other mean which can tell you if both the objects are same, instead of `hashCode`. It is possible to have same hash code for two different models.

Read third bullet point in `hashCode` method [documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)

Comment: I tried by changing hashcode to Id comparison but no luck.same issue is there.. 
Suppose we have three data , one is 16th October,  2nd is 15 September, 3rd is 3rd July, then If I try to change 15 September lower than 3rd July..not updating but if I try to change it greater than 16th October, then it's updating.. not getting why it's happening.. Year is same for all three dates

Comment: Just print all the elements in your list after updating the list. this will help you to narrow down the error. If your list doesn't represent correct data, then its a problem on updating part of list. if the list represent correct data, then you have a problem in Implementation of `SortedList.Callback`.